# Facebook Graph API using ASP.NET with fancybox

Tags: facebook, fancybox, facebook-graph-api

Anyone know of some trick I can use to get facebook to authenticate a user within a fancybox iFrame? ... when I use the following code facebook dosent present the user with a login box, rather it gives them a link to facebook which puts the user back in the parent window

```
<a id="aFbLogin" href="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=http://ahost.com/callback.aspx&scope=email" type="text/html"><img style="border-style: none" 
                src="/Images/fBookLogin.png" alt="FaceBook Login Button" 
                title="Login with FaceBook" id="btnFbLogin" height="36" width="67" /></a>
```

Then some JavaScript to add the click event handler ... the pop up works .. but Facebook seems to not like being in an Fancybox-iFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has various measures (using css and javascript) in place to ensure that it is never hosted in an iframe. I'm afraid you are limited to using the popup implementation provided with the javascript sdk.